# Eclipse plugin issue with CDT plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried to manually uninstall the Eclipse CDT so that I can re-install it.
I followed the instructions here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_uninstall_CDT.3F

and to reinstall, I followed the instructions here: https://polarssl.org/kb/compiling-and-building/setup-eclipse-cdt-environment-on-windows

However, I get an error that:

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"C/C++ Development Tools SDK" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"C/C++ Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
```

How can I properly reinstall CDT ?
The first time I installed, Eclipse was abruptly stopped due to a BSOD. So I decided to reinstall and here I have hit a wall :p

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not uninstall a plugin (but just hides it from you), if there are dependencies from other plugins into your to be uninstalled plugins. For instance, if you have installed ADT with all plugins, then the Android Native Development Toolkit has a dependency to CDT and will therefore prohibit an uninstallation.

If nothing else works, you may want to try a clean re-installation. That's quite easy (at least since 3.7 upwards): From your current installation, run File -> Export -> Installation -> To file. That will create a "receipe" of installed features. You can then install them using the same menu (under Import) into a clean Eclipse package and just leave the CDT away.